# Rates Involving 2 or more variables

Tags: calculus

The radius of a cylindrical pipe 2m long expands with heat at a constant rate of 0.0012 mm/s. Find the rate at which the volume of the pipe will be increasing when its radius is 19mm.

I've tried doing this question finding dV/dr and dV/dt as I know that dr/dt = 0.0012mm/s and the volume of the cylinder. However, my answer every time is very far off from 0.287mm^3/s which is the answer give. Help please?

Comment: Show us how you arrived at your answer, and we can more easily help you.

Comment: Are you doing the unit conversion between m and mm properly?

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the length of the pipe, so $L=2000$ mm, and let $r$ be the radius. The volume of the cylindrical pipe is then

$$V=\pi r^2L$$

Taking the derivative, and remembering that $L$ is constant,

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=2\pi rL\frac{dr}{dt}$$

Now substituting the values $L=2000,r=19,\frac{dr}{dt}=0.0012$, we get

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=2\pi(19)(2000)(0.0012)\approx 287$$

So the answer is $287 \text{ mm}^3/\text{s}$. Your textbook is wrong. Probably the answer writer forgot to convert the length from meters to millimeters: that would result in the "answer" you gave. Or perhaps the desired unit was $\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$.